# What is causing $ to be undefined? (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jslint

I am practicing my JQuery at the moment, and I cannot understand how to make this error message go away: **'$' was used before it was defined.** The code seems to work though. Nothing wrong with it.

I downloaded the latest version of JQuery, using a Safari browser, and writing my code in the Brackets text editor.

The Javascript code I have is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("h2").mouseenter(function () {
      $("h2").fadeTo('fast', 0);
   });
   $("h2").mouseleave(function () {
      $("h2").fadeTo('fast', 1);
   });
});
```

Below is a screenshot of the my code + error message

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please include your actual code in the question, not a screenshot of it.

Comment: And FWIW, this is not an (runtime) error, it's a lint warning. Please make yourself familiar with the tools you are using before you use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell JSLint it is a global. Add this comment to the top of your file:

```
/*global $, jQuery*/
```